# Can’t update Cordova and Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I can't update cordova to 5.1.1 and Ionic to 1.6.4. When running

```
npm update -g cordova
```

nothing happens.

When running:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

i get:

```
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.7.3"})
npm WARN engine cordova-js@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.7.3"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.7.3"})
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
/usr/bin/cordova -> /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@5.1.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── cordova-lib@5.1.1 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, rc@0.5.2, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, elementtree@0.1.6, d8@0.4.4, request@2.47.0, tar@1.0.2, glob@4.0.6, cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.9, init-package-json@1.7.1, plist@1.1.0, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, npm@1.3.4, cordova-js@4.0.0)
```

Also Ionic reminds me to update:

```
Ionic CLI is out of date:
 * Locally installed version: 1.3.14
 * Latest version: 1.6.4
 * https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
 * Run npm install -g ionic to update
```

But i can't do it.

After installing Cordova and Ionic i still have

```
cordova -v
4.3.0
```

and

```
ionic -v
1.3.14
```

How can i update?

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: I think you  have to try like uninstall first and then install. Uninstall both and install both

Comment: Try updating npm, also it could be a user rights issue.. try using sudo.

Comment: I tried it all (unistalling, updating node and npm, using sudo). It didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I've found something interesting: there are free `node_modules` directories in my computer. In `cordova/RELEASENOTES.md` I've found three different cordova versions


1. in `home/node_modules` there is cordova 5.1.1 

2. in `usr/lib/node_modules` there is cordova 5.2.0

3. in `usr/local/lib/node modules` there is cordova 4.3.0


Why there are three `node_modules` directories and how can I use the newest cordova?

Comment: I had the same issue, npm update didn't do anything, npm install -g cordova did install the update (even without removing node_modules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of node and npm installed.

Then try uninstalling cordova/ionic and then reinstalling it again.

Note that using npm update doesn't actually update the node package, but the node_modules within that package.

Comment: I've deleted all "node_modules" folders and then reinstalled Cordova and Ionic. It work. Thanks.

Comment: Deleting just the cordova folder in /node_modules and doing a new cordova install worked for me: npm install -g cordova

Answer (score 3):

Uninstalling and reinstalling as mentioned in many places wasn't working for me.

So I deleted the the dir 'cordova' in:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

like this:

```
sudo rm cordova -R
```

then:
    npm install npm -g

then:

```
sudo npm uninstall cordova -g
```

then:

```
sudo npm install cordova -g
```

And it worked. A similar method might work in Windows too

Comment: After this process, I also had to resolve the npm warning about minimatch version, "npm update -g minimatch@3.0.2"